# Controlling schema created by Database.Persist

Tags: sql, sqlite, haskell, yesod

I'm learning Haskell, and my first real app is a web application using Yesod + Database.Persist with the SQLite backend, but I can't find a way to specify some things with the `persistLowerCase` quasi quoter:

- How to declare a specified column should be indexed (without the uniqueness constraint)
- How to specify foreign keys (I can only do `foreign_table_id ForeignTableId`, which translates to `"foreign_table_id" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "foreign_table"`)
- How to specify column sizes (`VARCHAR(50)`, for instance)
- How to use `CHAR` and `BLOB` as a column type

The last two are not useful for SQLite proper, but I might change database backends in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly (from a presentation about Yesod at InfoQ), adding an index must be done manually, there's no support in Yesod for doing it automatically.

Column sizes can be specified by typing `maxlen=<size>` in the field definition. `BLOB`s can be stored as a `ByteString`s. An example for both fields looks like this:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
    Something
        b           ByteString
        t           Text         maxlen=30
|]
```

The `BLOB` data type will work with Sqlite3, since I've used it in the past, but I don't know for sure about the `maxlen` attribute, I just read about it. You can find more details in the Yesod book, [chapter about Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_attributes).

As for the foreign keys, my experience tells me that those are synonyms. Just don't forget to enable foreign keys, since they're [disabled by default](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: Is there a reference for attributes? Neither the Yesod book nor wiki seem to have one. `maxlen`, for instance, is never mentioned.

Comment: Oh...I was sure that the book mentions it, but apparently I'm wrong. I can't find any other references for `maxlen` except the Yesod code itself (there's a merge from 2 years ago here: https://github.com/meteficha/persistent/commit/881a9c4289ee72af643968b89037cb23a0169633). But I just tried it in Haskell Center with `persistent-mysql` and it works fine. Here's the log output: `[Debug#SQL] "CREATE TABLE \`something\`(\`id\` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\`blob\` BLOB NOT NULL,\`text\` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL)"`